# issues about argument substitution and control sequence definition

Tags: expl3, arguments, definition

I want to define a command to receive an environment name list (and other argument to control the behavior of the environment, I remove them for simplify) and define these environments, but it does not behave as expected.

As Ulrike Fischer commented, I should pass `##1` to `\__test:nnnn`, but if `\NewDocumentEnvironment` is nested deeper, `####1`, `########1` and so on are too long to use, is there any way to still use `#1` to represent the argument of `\NewDocumentEnvironment`?

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__test:nnnn
  {
    \typeout{#3}% ##1
    \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
      {
        \typeout{#3}% 'a', 'b', 'c'
        \NewDocumentEnvironment { test##1 } { #2 }
          { #3 } { #4 }
      }
  }

\__test:nnnn { a, b, c } { m } { #1 } { }

% cause error
% Illegal parameter number in definition of \__clist_map_1:w.
% \__test:nnnn { e, f } { m +b } { #1 #2 } { }
\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
% output 'a' which should be 'test'
\begin{testa}{test}
\end{testa}
\end{document}
```

Comment: you need to call it with `\__test:nnnn { a, b, c } { m } { ##1 } { }`. But why are you defining three environments which all do the same thing?

Comment: @UlrikeFischer For simplify, I remove the extra argument, they are just almost the same, is there a way to use #1 instead of ##1 ?

Comment: @ZhiyuanLck Whatever you put in the fourth argument, you'll end up with three environments defined in exactly the same way. What's this useful for?

Comment: @egreg I want to define a lot of similar environments that associate with a group name, and inside the environment there is a local command say `\save` to save some content in a sequence such as `\g__save_<group_name>_<i'th group>_seq` for later use. Cauze there will be multiple `\save` commands inside the environment, it is better to use `\save` instead of `\save{<group name>}...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure how useful this is. Anyway, you can avoid doubling `#` in the third and fourth argument by storing the arguments is token list variables before doing the mapping.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse}
\ExplSyntaxOn
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__zhiyuan_test_defenv:nnnn
 {
  \tl_set:Nn \l__zhiyuan_scratch_a_tl { #3 }
  \tl_set:Nn \l__zhiyuan_scratch_b_tl { #4 }
  \clist_map_inline:nn { #1 }
   {
    \__zhiyuan_newenv:nnVV { ##1 } { #2 } \l__zhiyuan_scratch_a_tl \l__zhiyuan_scratch_b_tl
   }
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__zhiyuan_newenv:nnnn
 {
  \NewDocumentEnvironment { test#1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \__zhiyuan_newenv:nnnn { nnVV }

\__zhiyuan_test_defenv:nnnn { a, b, c } { m } { #1 } { }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
% output 'a' which should be 'test'
\begin{testa}{test}
\end{testa}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Wow, I have thought about this way, but I forgot to use a `V` signature. By the way, is there no need to put a `\tl_clear_set:N <tl var>` before a `\tl_set:Nn <tl var>`?

Comment: @ZhiyuanLck There is no `\tl_clear_set:N`, but no need to do `\tl_clear:N` either: with `\tl_set:Nn` the possible contents of the variable is overwritten anyway.